# how to pass data between two view controller that separated by UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to pass `User` Data  (object) from `LoginVC` to `HomeVC`, but between those two view controllers, it is separated by `UITabBarController` and `NavigationController` like the Image below:

I want to pass `User` Data  from this loginVC. from this loginVC, it will push segue to `main.storyboard` like the image below

[image]

here is the `main.storyboard` that contains tab bar controller, in the first tab bar (index = 0) is where the HomeVC located, I put the homeVC in the `Home.storyboard`
[image]

and here is the `Home.storyboard`, there is Navigation controller before I finally reach the HomeVC.
[image]

so how to pass data from LoginVC to HomeVC? it seems that I have to pass data from: LoginVC -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> HomeVC

what should I do ?

the User data is like the code below:

```
struct User {
    var username : String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var userCode : String
    var address: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var dateOfBirth: String
    var outlet : Outlet // custom object

    init (dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        username = dictionary["user_name"] as? String ?? ""
        firstName = dictionary["customers_firstname"] as? String ?? ""
        lastName = dictionary["customers_lastname"] as? String ?? ""
        userCode = dictionary["kode_customer"] as? String ?? ""
        address = dictionary["alamat_user"] as? String ?? ""
        phoneNumber = dictionary["customers_telephone"] as? String ?? ""
        dateOfBirth = dictionary["customers_dob"] as? String ?? ""
        outlet = Outlet(dictionary: dictionary)
    }



}
```

Comment: how you are navigating to LoginVC to mainTabbarVC can you post the code

Comment: Instead of passing `User` data from multiple controller, store `User` data in `UserDefault` and access those data in controller where you want.

Answer (score 1):

UITabBarController maintains the array of view controller, in order of tab index.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621185-viewcontrollers

And again same way UINavigationController also maintains the controller stack.

so you just need to get the object of your view controller from the array (by type casting it) and pass the data.

Answer (score 0):

User data is importment, you shall consider to save user data in local file, and then you can fetch user data everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController class contain an array of ViewControllers.

You can access the first ViewContoller using normal indexing inside any of view controller inside the UITabBarController:

```
self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[0]
```